# при клике на элемент получить координаты клика

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени!

Есть код:

```js
function showareabtn(el) {

  el.stopPropagation();
  console.log(el);
  var x = el.originalEvent.layerX;
  var y = el.originalEvent.layerY;

  alert(x + " x " + y);

}
```

```css
.areacol {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #F00;
}
```

```html
<div class="areacol" onclick="javascript:showareabtn(this);"></div>
```

Скрипт должен выводить координаты клика, но он выдает ошибку, подскажите пожалуйста, что не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно использовать не элемент, а событие `event`

```js
function showareabtn(el, event) {

  event.stopPropagation();
  //console.log(el);
  var x = event.layerX;
  var y = event.layerY;

  alert(x + " x " + y);

}
```

```css
.areacol {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #F00;
}
```

```html
<div class="areacol" onclick="javascript:showareabtn(this, event);"></div>
```

Comment: Ошибочка в коде) event то не передается как параметр.

Comment: @alexoander, поправила, пусть передается

Answer (score 2):

> спасибо, но в силу специфики мне нужно что бы запускался скрипт именно
>   через onclick и функцию, как нибудь можно это адаптировать под такое
>   событие?

Вот так:

```js
function showareabtn(el) {

  el.stopPropagation();
 
  var x = el.layerX;
  var y = el.layerY;

  alert(x + " x " + y);

}
```

```css
.areacol {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #F00;
}
```

```html
<div class="areacol" onclick="(function(e){ showareabtn(e); })(event)"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

В своей функции вы работаете с элементом, по которому кликнули, а надо с объектом события:

```js
function showareabtn(e) {
  var e = $.Event(e);
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log(e);
  var x = e.originalEvent.layerX;
  var y = e.originalEvent.layerY;

  alert(x + " x " + y);
}
```

```css
.areacol {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #F00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="areacol" onclick="showareabtn(event);"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо, но в силу специфики мне нужно что бы запускался скрипт именно через onclick и функцию, как нибудь можно это адаптировать под такое событие?

Comment: Поправил для вашей "специфики"